# Why was Bitlocker Recovery triggered on new working Ideapad laptop?

Tags: windows, laptop, encryption

Starting today, my Ideapad 5 laptop that I bought in May and have been taking care of, only shows the Bitlocker Recovery screen upon boot, preventing me from proceeding into Windows. I do not know my Bitlocker key - however, this was not a problem before, and I am not sure what exactly changed in the boot process to prompt Bitlocker recovery to activate.

The backstory:

I bought the laptop earlier this year. Upon setting it up, I was unpleasantly surprised by the need for a compulsory Microsoft account to activate Windows 11, and instead used a workaround to create a simple Username + Password user profile that I could unlock the laptop with, as you would on an older system like Windows 7. The process I used was from this website: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/install-windows-11-without-microsoft-account .
Importantly this means that my laptop is not associated with any Microsoft account.

Last week I allowed my laptop to install a Windows update. After that I did not use it.

Today upon booting it up I was prompted to enter the Bitlocker Key for the drive. This is usually found on one's Microsoft account, but as I never made one, I cannot retrieve it from there.

My only hope now, I take it, is to restore the previous conditions under which the system booted, to stop the TPM from withholding the Bitlocker Key from Windows. But since my laptop did not experience any significant changes I cannot imagine how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you have Secure Boot enabled or disabled?

Comment: It was enabled.

Comment: Try to disable Secure Boot feature in BIOS.

Comment: If that doesn't help, then you have basically lost your disk.